# ViewImports to register tag helper not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have created a Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core 2.0.

It runs fine if I include the following line at the top of the page (.cshtml)

```
@addTagHelper *, DanLife
```

If I remove this line and place it into _ViewImports.cshtml the tag helper no longer works.

```
@using DanLife.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, DanLife
```

The assembly name is DanLife.

The web application uses areas.

I would like to know why my tag helpers are not registering for using in my views when registered in _ViewImports.cshtml.

Answer (score 6):

Solved - make sure your _ViewImports.cs file within the areas is in the "Views" folder and not "Shared".

Comment: wish there was a common _ViewImports.cshmtl

Answer (score 5):

you must copy and past _ViewImports.cshtml in all folder view if you using area in project

Answer (score 0):

Move _ViewImports.cshtml to appllication root directory.

*A _ViewImports.cshtml in the application root folder will apply to all views in the app.*
[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0#_viewimportscshtml)